# What is considered best practice for handling many input fields in a form element? React

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, state

Assume we have a react component that has a form element with many input fields of various types. Let's also assume we have a button that, when clicked, sends over every input field of the form to some function.

In this scenario, is it considered good practice to have an onChange in every input field and have a different handle change function for each input field? That way, everything should be updated before button gets clicked. However, this approach just doesn't seem feasible to use if you have some arbitrarily large number of input fields, say 100. I don't want to write 100+ different handle change functions for this one component. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a unique name (or id) to every input, after that you can have a local state in your component and only one `onChange` method. So the idea is that you do something like this:

for local state you have:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});
```

and for onChange you have:

```
const onChange = (e) => {
  setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

As you can see in `onChange` method I take the name of the input and assign it the value of that input. That's why I said that name of every input should be unique.